# How to use RUN clone git in dockerfile

Tags: git, docker, github, dockerfile

Instead of using the ADD or COPY command I would like the docker image to download the python script (aa.py) that I want to execute from my git.
In mygit there is only one file called aa.py.

This doesn't work:

```
FROM python:3

RUN git clone https://github.com/user/mygit.git

CMD [ "python3", "./aa.py" ]
```

Error message:

```
ERR /usr/local/bin/python: can't open file './aa.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem here is `aa.py` file is in your current working directory

change the `Dockerfile` content to

```
FROM python:3
RUN git clone https://github.com/user/mygit.git
WORKDIR mygit
CMD [ "python3", "./aa.py" ]
```

OR

```
FROM python:3
RUN git clone https://github.com/user/mygit.git
CMD [ "python3", "mygit/aa.py" ]
```

Answer (score 7):

The best solution is to change docker working directory using `WORKDIR`. So your Dockerfile should look like this:

```
FROM python:3
RUN git clone https://github.com/user/mygit.git
WORKDIR mygit
CMD [ "python3", "./aa.py" ]
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The Docker best practices page warns against using `RUN cd ` commands instead of `WORKDIR`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `CMD` instruction can't find file `aa.py`.

You have to specify complete path to your `aa.py` which, if you didn't change the working directory will be `/project_name/aa.py`.